# Client certificate authentication in data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, client-certificates

I have a data factory that extracts data from Microsoft Graph and Defender for endpoint in another tenant. For authentication we use client credentials with service principal and secret which are saved in key vault.
[image]

This returns a bearer token which we use to then make the API calls and obtain data. The bearer token is valid for 60 minutes. The login is done for every pipeline as they are scheduled at different times for different purposes.
The client, however, has a requirement to use client certificate. We can only use key vault so no download/upload can be done. It needs to be handled in data factory. Can anyone advise?

The questions that concern me are whether it also returns a bearer token valid for one hour. Ideally the authentication should be done at the pipeline level not linked service level as there are different base URLs.

I think there is a way to use a similar approach to client credential we are using currently but the client certificate needs to be converted into jwt token I think, which I am unsure is possible in data factory.

Thank you.